# Which Cert template to AD-CS

Tags: windows-server-2016, certificate-authority

i have a windows server 2016 with the CA role installed. i created a CSR on an network appliance to allow ad auth using ssl/tls. When I try and import that .csr file in the Win CA gui the extension is not allowed.

Followed this [Blog/How-to](http://blog.ryanbetts.co.uk/2018/07/certificate-services-new-cert-req-from.html) and it tells me to use the cmd tool but you have to select cert template. which one would i use to authenticate user to a FW or an appliance like that?

PS: event viewer is tricky. which section shows the CS stuff going through  or failing ? the picture section doesn't seem to show all of my request for auth from the appliances. Maybe im missing something

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> select cert template. which one would i use to authenticate user

You should probably create a template just for that purpose. Using the built-in templates generally isn't a good practice.  If you wanted to just use a built in one, the 'Web Server' template will probably be fine.  The web server template has the most common extensions enabled for TLS Server usage.  The 'Computer' template may also have the required options.

Comment: sounds good ill look into making a custom one maybe copy the webserver one

Comment: so when you make the template how do you make a cert or a csr for the appliance/fw ?